How to make child element, with bigger width than parent, appear behind it in the z-axis
I have the following HTML structure::
<header style="width: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0; z-index:1;">
  <nav style="position: relative;">
    <button style="width: 20px; height: 4px;">
      Open nav
    </button>
    <ul style="width: 100vw; min-height: 100vh; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: -1;">
      <!-- Some links... -->
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
      <!-- Some content... -->
</main>
<footer>
      <!-- Some content... -->
</footer>

The structure above makes the ul element appear behind the nav element on the z-axis. However, because the nav element's width is 20px (because this is the width of the button) the ul element appears only behind those 20px and above everything else.
What I am trying to do is to make the ul element appear behind the content in the header element, and above the rest of the content on the page on the z-axis.
For incoming solutions, I would prefer to keep this HTML structure and only change CSS.
Thanks in advance!

What do you mean by showing elements behind nav, what is your goal, post any reference drawing or image, so I can help you

I want to make an animation that looks like the links list (the ul element) slides out of the header element once the open nav button is clicked. In the header element, there is more content besides the nav like a logo, so I want the links list to appear behind everything in the header element on the z-axis, but in front the rest of the page (main, footer...)

Your statement about the width of the nav element being 20px is incorrect. <nav> defaults to display: block; and in this example you have provided its width is 100% of the page, not 20px. Given that, you may be misunderstanding what you are even seeing here in general. Further, your example doesn't show the <ul> overlapping the <nav> at all due to how you have positioned things. If you can give an example of code that matches your description of it, and stating what you're trying to do from there, it would be much easier to help!

Thanks everyone for the help!
I was able to solve my issue using a wrapper around the ul element, moving the absolute positioning and 100 viewport width to the wrapper and adding overflow: hidden to it as well.
No z-index was needed at all.

Remove position: relative; on nav and position: fixed; on header. Because of both fixed relative they both have different stacking context.
Read this article to learn more about stacking context.

if you want to implement the z-index for your ul element, it needs to be positioned outside the header element
Here is what I think you want to achieve:


        <header style="width: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0; z-index: 1;">
            <nav style="position: relative;">
                <button style="width: 20px; height: 4px;">
                    Open nav
                </button>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <ul style="width: 100vw; min-height: 100vh; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: -1;">
            <!-- Some links... -->
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
            <li>Link 4</li>
        </ul>




Your ul element can be z-index: 0; if you don't have any other
element that has such property. So that will be your base stack
element.

